# non-linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have to solve a differential equation, which is non-linear and has several instances of y(x). In general

$y'(x)=g(x,y(x))$, or more specifically

$y'(x)=a(x,y(c_0)) y(x)^n +b(x,y(c_0)) y(x)^{n-1}$.

If it helps, assuming $n \in \{2,3,4\}$ is fine.

Is something like that even solvable, if yes, do you know a book or online tutorial which explains this?

I now tried it with Runga-Kutta, which is a numerical method. However, as $y'(x)$ depends on $y(c_0)$, which I do not know, this method does not work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: The notation $y(x)^{(n-1)}$ is unclear. Do you mean the $n-1$th power? In that case, you should write $y(x)^{n-1}.$ Or do you mean the $n-1$th derivative? In that case, you should write $y^{(n-1)}(x).$

Comment: Note that your second form is not in the class of the first form, as $x$ appears as separate variable. You would have to write $y'(x)=g(x,y(x))$ or set the coefficients in the second equation constant, $y'=ay^n+by^{n-1}$, which makes this separable.

Comment: Thank you Lutz and Adrian. I clarified now what I mean. I hope this helps and facilitates the understanding of the problem. It would be great, if you are now able to provide an idea to my problem.

Comment: I tried it now numerically, but still I do not get my head around :-(

Comment: It's been a long time since I last used these things, but numerical methods should work? Have yoiu tried an Euler method? (It's less efficient, but a simple starting point)

Comment: Hi David, I think Euler does not work as I $y(c_0)$ is not a value which I know.